# App script - Exception: You do not have permission to call setFontColor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to edit cells font based on other cells font on the same row but I can't edit their style using a custom function as I saw.

My question is how to achieve this then ?

Here is my code :

```
function colorCells(nameRange, valueRange) {
    var redHex = "#ff0000";
    var orangeHex = "#ff6d01";

    var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
    var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();

    var range = activeSheet.getRange(valueRange);
    var rangeColor = range.getFontColors();
    console.log(rangeColor);

    var newColors = rangeColor.map(r => r.includes(redHex) ? redHex : r.includes(orangeHex) ? orangeHex : '#000000');
    console.log(newColors);

    var rangeToColor = activeSheet.getRange(nameRange)
    
    for (let i = 1; i <= rangeToColor.getNumRows(); i++) {
      const cell = rangeToColor.getCell(i, 1);
      cell.setFontColor(newColors[i-1])
    }

    return "";
}
```

**EDIT :**

To explain my objective, I have a column of strings and for each a row of data. And I want some of the data have different font color based on conditional formatting.

So I want that if any data from a row is either red or orange the related column string change its color to the same one. Here is an example on an image.

Before applying the function/script :

[image]

After :

[image]

Comment: As far as I know a custom function can change only the cell which the formula belongs (and fill adjasted cells in some cases). It can read any range on the sheet, but don't change it. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#return_values

Comment: Ok so how can I do what I want ? Is it possible to select a range to edit ?

Comment: Isn't what you want able to be done by using [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413)? Specially activating the rules with the `Custom formula` option (it allows to get data from other cells).

Comment: Yes but conditional formatting cannot be applied to cell format, only values (or I'm not aware of it)

Comment: I believe it could be done with a script function that could be run via custom menu for example. How exactly it depends on your workflow. From your code I can't tell how exactly it could work. You need to describe more closely what you have, what you're doing and what you want to get.

Comment: I'm editing to precise my objective.

Comment: Sorry, it still eludes me, how it supposed to work.You change the numbers on the left side (recolor them some way) and you want that the texts in the first column to change their color automatically? What supposed to happen if I change the number '1' to orange color?

Comment: Yes that's exactly to happen. If the 1 changes to orange then the text of the column (here 'red') will color orange. They won't be 2 different colors on the same line.

Comment: About the image of `Here is an example on an image.`, in this case, it's the input situation? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the output situation you expect? If that image was the output situation, can you provide the input situation?

Comment: Updating the post to add I/O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you really want is to extract the colors on each row and then apply it to the column with names (independently of whatever name is there).

To do that, the simplest way is to make a function that extracts that information:

```js
const BLACK = '#000000'

function extractColumnColors(range) {
  return range.getFontColors()
    .map(rowColors => [
      rowColors.find(v => v !== BLACK) ?? BLACK
    ])
}
```

This function does the following:

1. Get the font color of the cells in the range (class `Range` not the A1 notation of it).
2. For each row, finds the first color that's not black and makes an array with a single element with it.
3. If all are black, the value in the array is black.

With all of that, the result is an array that contains arrays with a single color value, which is perfect because it allows to call `setFontColors` directly:

```js
function example() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Example')
  const nameRange = sheet.getRange('A1:A')
  const valuesRange = sheet.getRange('B1:C')

  const newColors = extractColumnColors(valuesRange)
  nameRange.setFontColors(newColors)
}
```

### References

- [Nullish coalescing operator (??)
  (MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)
- [Array.prototype.find() (MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)
- [Array.prototype.map() (MDN reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Range.prototype.getFontColors() (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getFontColors())
- [Range.prototype.setFontColors(colors) (Apps Script reference)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#setFontColors(Object))